# SED string with special characters divided by wildcard

Tags: bash, sed

Have issue with sed. I have sed like this

```
sed -i '' 's#\<script src\=\"http\:\/\/widget\.blah\.com\/js\/sis_some_widget.*.class\=\"sis\-some\-widget\"\>\<\/div\>#newblah.com#g' lol.sql .
```

Which supposed to replace whole script code with wildcard between two parts of the code. The thing is, that the part that is wildcarded is different for each and every script code (on many wordpress pages). The only common parts are `<script src="http://widget.blah.com/js/sis_some_widget.js?` and `class="sis-some-widget"></div>`

Help me figure out why this sed is not working, and how am I suppose to sed string with wildcard and many special characters.

Code looks like

`<script src="http://widget.blah.com/js/sis_some_widget.js?MANY MANY SPECIAL CHARACTERS and letters class="sis-some-widget"></div>`

Comment: note you can improve the visibility by using another delimiter: `sed 's#bla/ble#aa#'`

Comment: done, thanks buddy

Comment: the good thing of doing so is that you don't need to escape `/` anymore and you can write just `/`. That is, these are equivalent: `sed 's/a\/b/X\/Y/'` and  `sed 's#a/b#X/Y#'`.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37996544/2454357) helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding backslashes where you don't need them.  If you are using '#' as your delimiter, the only characters you need to escape are the dots in the domain name.

'\<', '\=', '-', etc. aren't valid character escapes, so sed interprets those backslashes as literal characters.

Your expression should be:

```
's#<script src="http://widget\.blah\.com/js/sis_some_widget.*class="sis-some-widget"></div>#newblah.com#g'
```